# Jpa-One To Many and Restws

Tags: rest, jpa, jaxb, jax-rs, one-to-many

I have two classes, Customer and CustomerProduct. I want the customerId(from customer) to be mapped in CustomerProduct. I used OneToMany mapping as follows.

Customer.java

```
@XmlTransient
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
public Set<CustomerProducts> getCustomerProducts() {
    return customerProducts;
}
```

CustomerProduct.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
```

I was able to save the datas, but for selecting a customer, I used named query which returned a Customer with CustomerProduct as well. I used restws. I used `Response.ok(cust).build();` where cust had all the values in the server side.

When I get the response in the client side, I am getting the customers but not the CustomerProduct. 
Did I miss something?

Comment: CustomerProduct sounds like a class for a link table, don't you want a ManyToMany relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `@XmlTransient` annotation, it prevents the `customerProducts` property from serialization to a response.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html

And to avoid infinity loop during serialization you either need add `@XmlTransient` to the `customer` property of the `CustomerProduct` entity or fetch this property lazily.

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. But this did not work either. got the following exception.

Comment: SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: com.utsch.orm.Customer@5a6bc6a7 -> com.utsch.orm.CustomerProducts@3d3224fa -> com.utsch.orm.Customer@5a6bc6a7]
 at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)